# how to show drop down list on top of drop down box (always)

Tags: css, angular, syncfusion

i am using syncfusion pager, dropdownlist in our application
please open the below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv6myv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

data will change based on the number of items selected from dropdown.
after selecting the 20 items from drop down go to bottom of the page by scrolling.
drop down list is showing bottom of the drop down box. but i want to show dropdown list items always top of the dropdown box.

Please provide any solution.

Comment: can't it be fixed using z-index?

Comment: i don't know how to implement z-index please provide a solution

Comment: it's a css attribute wherein div can be arranged on whose on top and whose on bottom. just get the id of the divs, for example: `#div_top { z-index:9; }` `#div_bottom{ z-index:-1; }`

Comment: sorry , @kapitan not working

Comment: i just seen your code on your link, i recommend putting your list items inside the card-body tag then put your dropdown div on the card-footer tag. here's some help: [bootstrap-header-and-footer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#header-and-footer)

Comment: thanks @kapitan, will try and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188098/discussion-between-santhosh-and-kapitan).

Answer (score 0):

i just saw your code on your link, and i tried this:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let student of tempArray">
    <div class='card-body'>
        <p class="text-truncate">{{student.name}} &nbsp; &nbsp; {{student.standard}}</p>    
    </div>    
    </div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='card-body'>
      <div class="fixed-footer" *ngIf="students.length > paginationData[0].value">
<ejs-pager  [pageCount]="3" [pageSize]="value" (click)="selectedPage($event)"
 [totalRecordsCount]='students.length'></ejs-pager>
<ejs-dropdownlist [dataSource]="paginationData" [fields]="fields" (change)="valueChange($event)" [popupHeight]=150 [value]="value"></ejs-dropdownlist>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i did here is that i put the list items and the drop down box on a separate card.

it's a little messy, just please arrange the indentions.

Answer (score 0):

In the dropdownlist open event, you can get the popupHight and set a negative value into popup **offsetY** property, refer to below code.

```
onddlPopupOpen(event: PopupEventArgs, ddlObj) {
    event.popup.offsetY = -(parseInt(ddlObj.popupHeight));
    event.popup.collision = { X: 'fit', Y: 'fit' };
    event.popup.dataBind();
    event.popup.refreshPosition(ddlObj.element, false);
}
```

This will open the popup in the top.

[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ajxwo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)